# How to get and compare data type for all the values for similar columns in two dataframes in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I have two files with the same column names. I created two data frames by reading these `CSV` files. Consider a column named `Units Sold`. By default, its data type is a `string` when I checked the schema. Now, I want to iterate through each row of data for this column in both the data frames and check whether the data type is correct or not.

If a column is `numeric` in one file then it should be the same in the second one if one file is having value as `345` and another is having `345.00` then highlight since the data type is different over here. I tried below thing but this very generic:

```
types1=[df1.dtypes]
#print(types1)
types2 =[df2.dtypes]
#print(types2)

if(types1==types2):
    print("Data types is equal for both the files..")
else:
    print("Data types is NOT equal for both the files..")
```

Below is the column and sample data:

```
Units Sold
8446
3018
1517
3322
9845
9528
```

I didn't find any relevant posts for my problem. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and had to loop over the columns. the problem I had is that some numeric columns were sometimes read as a string because of an NA value indicator.

here is my code chunck to check types (I assume that the 2 dataframes have the same columns with exactly the same names) I also tweaked it to have the same output as you :

```
df1_types = pd.DataFrame(df1.dtypes,columns=["colname", "type"])
df2_types = pd.DataFrame(df2.dtypes,columns=["colname", "type"])
flag = True
for index, row in df1_types.iterrows():
    if row['type'] != df2_types[df2_types['colname'] == row['colname']]['type'].values[0]:
        # Add numeric check here if needed
        flag = False
        break
if flag:
    print("Data types is equal for both the files..")
else:
    print("Data types is NOT equal for both the files..")
```

You have to add some custom check for numeric columns in the commented zone.

Comment: Hey! thanks for the reply. I got this error when ran your code `'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'values'`

Comment: what is the type of your dtypes object? (can you add it's print to your question) I think we don't use the same pyspark version.

Comment: My version is 2.4.4

Comment: I just adapted the solution, the dtypes returns a list of tuple, not an indexed list.

Comment: Okay, but it will check for the specific column passed right ?

Comment: and add you specific cases about numerics in the commented zone. I don't see your data so I can't do it

Comment: I don't want to use Pandas. Is there any way without using it? Also, is there any way to make it generic? Like, without checking for specific column

Comment: I have also added a column with its sample data...similar data is available in the second file..so how would your code run for this data?

Comment: And can you demonstrate some numeric validation for my dataset?